# Loop in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code. The Problems are: I want to change the image size from the imagefile which is insert in the left header and the loop stops after 2 files. I can't find my problem:

How do I set the Imagesize and how to apply the changes to every file in a folder?

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'ALLE XLS FILES AUTOMATISCH MODIFIZIEREN'
'VARIABLEN'
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim ImagePath As String
Dim Validation As String

'PFAD ZUM KUNDENLOGO
  ImagePath = "C:\logo.jpg"
'FIRMENNAME'
  companyname = "FIRMENNAME"
'AUFTRAGSNUMMER'
  contractnumber = "23-23"

'Geschwindigkeitsoptimierung
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Ordnerauswahl
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'Bei Abbruch
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Dateiendung (XLS)
  myExtension = "*.xls*"
'Dateiendung (XLS)
  myExtension2 = "*.xlsx*"


'Zielordner mit Endung xls
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
'Zielordner mit Endung xlsx
  myFile2 = Dir(myPath & myExtension2)
```

The loop for xls files:

```
'Loop durch alle XLS Files
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Variable wird umbenannt
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Warten bis Worksheet geöffnet ist
      DoEvents

    'CODE FÜR ÄNDERUNGEN
    'PRÜFEN OB LOGO EXISTIERT
      On Error Resume Next
        Validation = Dir(ImagePath)
      On Error GoTo 0

      If Validation = "" Then
        MsgBox "Pfad zu Logo falsch: " & ImagePath
        Exit Sub
      End If

    'LOGO IN JEDES AKTIVE SHEET EINFÜGEN
      For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sheet.activate
        'VARIABLEN FÜR SHEET POSITIONS ("LeftFooter","CenterFooter","RightFooter", "LeftHeader","CenterHeader","RightHeader")
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = ImagePath
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10&F © " + companyname + ", Vertragsnummer: " + contractnumber
          sheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

      Next sheet

    'Speichern und schliessen
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Warten bis workbook geschlossen ist
      DoEvents

    'Nächstes File
      myFile = Dir
  Loop
```

The loop for all xlsx files:

```
' LOOP DURCH ALLE XLSX FILES'
  Do While myFile2 <> ""
    'Variable wird umbenannt
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile2)

    'Warten bis Worksheet geöffnet ist
      DoEvents

    'CODE FÜR ÄNDERUNGEN
    'PRÜFEN OB LOGO EXISTIERT
      On Error Resume Next
        Validation = Dir(ImagePath)
      On Error GoTo 0

      If Validation = "" Then
        MsgBox "Pfad zu Logo falsch: " & ImagePath
        Exit Sub
      End If

    'LOGO IN JEDES AKTIVE SHEET EINFÜGEN
      For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sheet.activate
        'VARIABLEN FÜR SHEET POSITIONS ("LeftFooter","CenterFooter","RightFooter", "LeftHeader","CenterHeader","RightHeader")
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&G"
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture.Filename = ImagePath
          sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&""Arial,Standard""&10&F © " + companyname + ", Vertragsnummer: " + contractnumber
          sheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

      Next sheet

    'Speichern und schliessen
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Warten bis workbook geschlossen ist
      DoEvents

    'Nächstes File
      myFile2 = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box
  MsgBox "Fertig"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Optimierungen
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When you try iterating using `Dir` it is not allowed to use `Dir` again, except `myFile = Dir`. So, no `myFile2 = Dir(myPath & myExtension2)`, no `Validation = Dir(ImagePath)`. For the last case (`Validation`) you should use `FileSystemObject` and its `FileExists` method. About `myFile2 = Dir(myPath & myExtension2)`, you should try placing the code line after the first loop, but like `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension2)` and try putting a label (`DoItAgain:`) after the line `myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)`. And use a boolean variable to avoid staying in an infinite loop.

Comment: But what extension would you have for the case of `"*.xlsx*"`? It is anyhow included in/covered by `"*.xls*"` and it looks useless...  So it is unnecessary and avoid the second not accepted `Dir`...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When i remove the whole second loop and only use the first one it also stops after the first modified file

Comment: Did you removed ` Validation = Dir(ImagePath)`, too?

Comment: Edit: It works! Do you also know how to set image size in the macro?

Comment: You must create an object for `sheet.PageSetup.LeftHeaderPicture` and then using it. For what your code does now and for setting its size. It should have `Width` (or `SizeWidth`, I cannot check now...) and `Height` which can be modified as you need.

Comment: Did you understand how to replace `Validation = Dir(ImagePath)`, if you need this check?

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you find the appropriate object to use in order to modify the picture size?

Comment: Yes I could apply the picture size with an object. Needed a bit of time to figure it out but works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Try declaring the picture `As Graphic`. In this way you will benefit of intellisense suggestions...